# Given vectors $q, r$ prove that $qq^T \otimes rr^T = (q \otimes r) (q \otimes r)^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces):

[image]

I think it is essentially synonymous with following where $q,r$ are two column vectors of size $n \times 1$:

$qq^T \otimes rr^T = (q \otimes r) (q \otimes r)^T$

Can anyone show me how to prove this? How do I get a succint formula for $i,j$-th element of LHS and RHS?

Comment: This is simply an instance of the [mixed-product property of the Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Properties): whenever all expressions are defined, we have
$$
(A \otimes B)(C \otimes D) = (AC) \otimes (BD).
$$
Combine that with the fact that $(A \otimes B)^T = A^T \otimes B^T$.

Comment: please **prove** those two properties and post as answer

Comment: Could you provide some context for all this? See [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) for what I mean by "context". It is strange to me that you are requesting proofs for fairly standard results: I would think that wherever you encountered the Kronecker product for the first time (in a textbook/in a class), both of these statements would have been covered.

Comment: I am trying to work out equation 3 in John S. Bell's paper - On the EPR Paradox. I think it relies on this property. That is the context but I think it would have caused confusion and that is why did not provide any context. Can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces which is related and same thing. I can see things stated as facts. I'd like to see proofs please.

Comment: Thanks for that. For the mixed product property, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3739440/81360). Let me know if that answer is clear (are you comfortable with Einstein notation?). If I find the time, I'll put a proof of the transpose property into an answer.

Comment: Are $q,r$ row-vectors or column-vectors in this context? Until now, I was under the impression they were column-vectors

Comment: column vectors - Yes.

Comment: If that's the case, then I don't see the connection between your statement and the Wikipedia statement

Comment: that is why I had initially opted to leave out the context from my question. The connection is there. in fact its synonymous - another way of saying the exact same thing.